# Getting "No Session found for current thread" exception when using getCurrentSession()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring MVC 4.0.6 and Hibernate 4.3.5 . I am trying to insert values to my database table but I am getting this error message:

***HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread***

Currently I am using `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` to save my data , but if I use `getSessionFactory().openSession();` it works perfectly. I have heard I should use `getCurrentSession` instead of `getSessionFactory().openSession();` because it creates a new session every time I make a database query.

Could you please see my code below and tell me what I am doing wrong and how to get `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` working ?

**GradeServiceImpl:**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class GradeServiceImpl implements GradeService {

 @Autowired
 private GradeDao gradeDao;

 @Override
 public void addGrade(Grade grade) {

    gradeDao.addGrade(grade);
 }
}
```

**GradeDaoImpl**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class GradeDaoImpl implements GradeDao {

 @Autowired
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
 }

 public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
 }
 @Override
 public void addGrade(Grade grade) {

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(grade);

 }
}
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

   <annotation-driven />
   <context:annotation-config />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring" />


   <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
   <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
   <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
      <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </beans:bean>

   <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java" />
      <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
      <beans:property name="password" value="" />
   </beans:bean>

   <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
      <beans:property name="basename" value="resources/messages" />
      <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
   </beans:bean>

   <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <!-- <beans:property name="configLocation">
        <beans:value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:property>    -->
      <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.spring" />
      <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
         <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
         </beans:props>
      </beans:property>
   </beans:bean>

   <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
   </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
   <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <!-- Processes application requests -->
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

#### Update - Stack trace

**exception**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

**root cause**

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:106)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    com.spring.org.dao.GradeDaoImpl.addGrade(GradeDaoImpl.java:33)
    com.spring.org.service.GradeServiceImpl.addGrade(GradeServiceImpl.java:25)
    com.spring.org.GradeController.saveGrade(GradeController.java:32)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: How do you get your spring context?

Comment: According to my knowledge, your problem is *it is fine if application managed transaction is used, but is not fine on JTA managed transaction. I think you need to configure correctly JTA manged one if you want to use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`* !!!

Comment: @Narmer, if you meant to see my `web.xml` file, please check the updated code above.

Comment: Can you also add your stack trace? In which case you get the error?

Comment: You are mixing servlet-context and root-context. Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components, DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure. All of your Hibernate configuration should be in root-context. But I don't think this solves the problem though.

Comment: @Narmer, Please check the updated part of my code above. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I was using annotation based configuration, I have configured sessionfactory, datasource and transaction manager every thing. but I did not give @EnableTransactionManagement annotation at AppConfig class.

The code looks like below after adding the transaction annotation.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.bmp.*")
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource("classpath:${env}.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {
-----
}
```

The above annotations resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Narmer, you put all your database configuration in `servlet-context.xml` when it should go in `root-context.xml`. But the real cause of the problem (or a symptom of it) is that you use no transactional proxy as it can be seen in stacktrace : `GradeController.saveGrade` directly calls `GradeServiceImpl.addGrade` that in turn directly calls `GradeDaoImpl.addGrade`.

Normally, you should put the `@Transactional` annotation only in service layer, and not in dao layer (only one transactional layer). And you should verify that you autowire the service from the controller as

```
@Autowired
private GradeService gradeService;
```

Please try to use only one transactional layer and say if stacktrace shows a transactional proxy usage.

Edit :

There is another problem in your config : you have no `<tx:annotation-driven/>` tag, when it is necessary for spring to correctly process `@Transactional` annotations.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Did you remove the transactional annotation from the DAO ?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, I tried removing the transactional annotation from the DAO but it didn't make any differnece. thanks

Comment: @black_belt I've just found another problem and updated my answer. Could you please try and report whether it works ?

Answer (score 1):

in your hibernate properties, add this line.

```
 <beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</beans:prop>
```

so your hibernateProperties looks like this,

```
  <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
     <beans:props>
        <beans:prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</beans:prop>
        //add this
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
     </beans:props>
```

you need to open a transaction.
So do like this.

```
public void addGrade(Grade grade) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
     Transaction tx = null;
     try{
     tx = session.beginTransaction();
     session.save(grade);   
     tx.commit();
       }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
     }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tried your code, but when I submit my form I get this error message: `org.hibernate.HibernateException: save is not valid without active transaction
 org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
 com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.save(Unknown Source)
 com.spring.org.dao.GradeDaoImpl.addGrade(GradeDaoImpl.java:33)
 com.spring.org.service.GradeServiceImpl.addGrade(GradeServiceImpl.java:25)
 com.spring.org.GradeController.saveGrade(GradeController.java:32)`

Comment: try this, you need to open a transaction.

Comment: Well I think it will finally work, but you are doing *by hand* what spring can do for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the @Transactional annotation on your DAO implementation. Instead in your Service method;

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addGrade(Grade grade) {
    gradeDao.addGrade(grade);
}
```

Only service implementation required @Transactional for all database operations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's whats happening:

When you use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` instead of `sessionFactory.openSession()` hibernate would look for a session instance bound to application context thread **(in other words a single session instance would be managed by hibernate and returned when getCurrentSession() is called on session factory) .**

Now to configure a session bound to application context thread you must specify it in hibernate properties. You can do it by adding following property to `hibernateProperties` :

```
<beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</beans:prop>
```

The reason `sessionFactory.openSession()` works fine without above hibernate property is hibernate does not look for a `session` bound to application context, it needs to create a new session instance everytime you call `openSession()` on `sessionFactory`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks your reply. I tried your code, but when I submit my form I get this error message: `org.hibernate.HibernateException: save is not valid without active transaction
 org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
 com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.save(Unknown Source)
 com.spring.org.dao.GradeDaoImpl.addGrade(GradeDaoImpl.java:33)
 com.spring.org.service.GradeServiceImpl.addGrade(GradeServiceImpl.java:25)
 com.spring.org.GradeController.saveGrade(GradeController.java:32)`

Answer (score -2):

try to use older version of spring... Im using spring 3.2.8.RELEASE with hibernate 4.2.11.Final...

Comment: how would this help the cause.